# WebSite - SimpleSAMLphp - Facebook Workplace authorization

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp, facebook-workplace

I need to realize synchronous user account authorization of our website and "Facebook Workplace" service.

I need do it via SSO SAML, and I know about the SimpleSAMLphp application which can help with it.

I have a FBWP SSO config page and installed SimpleSAMLphp in subfolder of our website.

How I must configure SimpleSAMLphp for "Facebook Workplace"(FBWP) for synchronous authorization of accounts?

screenshot with FBWP configuration page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your saml20-sp-remote.php add the appropriate metadata.

```
$metadata['https://www.facebook.com/company/xxxxxxxxxx'] = array (
'entityid' => 'https://www.facebook.com/company/xxxxxxxxxx',
'contacts' =>
    array (
    ),
'metadata-set' => 'saml20-sp-remote',
'AssertionConsumerService' =>
    array (
        0 =>
            array (
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
                'Location' => 'https://yourcompany.facebook.com/work/saml.php',
                'index' => 0,
                'isDefault' => true,
            ),
    ),
'SingleLogoutService' =>
    array (
    ),
'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'username',
'validate.authnrequest' => false,
'saml20.sign.assertion' => false,
```

);